# Dyamically inserting array back into HTML from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

In short, I'm trying to figure out how to change an HTML drop down based upon a selection made in another HTML dropdown. Something like [this](http://javascript.about.com/library/bldydrop1.htm) is the end product.. where you select something in the first box, and the second box populates based upon that first option.

However, I've become stuck at how to populate that second box with the code I have. It's not as simple as adding  as the code creates arrays for all the options you have.

Some of the snippets I have are laid out like this.. (Javascript first)

```
function setModelLevels(mdlselc){
    var selection = mdlselc;
    if (selection == "nam_ncep" || selection == "nam_4km_ncep" || selection == "gfs_ncep" || selection == "rap_ncep" || selection == "wrf_nmm_ncep" || selection == "wrf_arw_ncep"){

    levelDyMenuItems = new Array();
    numDyLevelMenuItems = 0;
    makeDyLevelMenuItem("sfc","***Surface***","","level")
    makeDyLevelMenuItem("sfc","Surface","SELECTED ","level")
    makeDyLevelMenuItem("pcp","Precip","","level")
    makeDyLevelMenuItem("windvector","Wind Vector","","level")
    makeDyLevelMenuItem("windgust","Wind Gusts","","level")
    makeDyLevelMenuItem("ref","Simulated Reflectivity","","level")
    } //Ends Model check
} //Ends setModelLevels
```

(HTML next)

```
<TR><TD>
<SELECT NAME="model" CLASS="controls1" onchange=setModelLevels(document.controls.model[document.controls.model.selectedIndex].value);>

<SCRIPT>
 createMenuItems();
 for (i = 1; i <= numModelMenuItems; i++) { document.writeln('<OPTION ' +  modelMenuItems[i].modelDefault + 'VALUE="' + modelMenuItems[i].modelValue + '">' + modelMenuItems[i].modelLabel) }
</SCRIPT>

</SELECT>

</TD></TR><TR><TD>

<SELECT NAME="level" id="levelsel" CLASS="controls1">

<SCRIPT>
for (i = 1; i <= numDyLevelMenuItems; i++) { document.writeln('<OPTION ' + levelDyMenuItems[i].levelLabel + 'VALUE="' + levelDyMenuItems[i].levelValue + '">' + levelDyMenuItems[i].levelLabel) }
</SCRIPT>

</SELECT>

</TD></TR>
```

(The code isn't mine, it's a somewhat publicly available weather model animator that I'm messing around with on my side.)

So basically, when you change the dropdown with the NAME="model", it drops the name of the model into the setModelLevels code. That sees what model you've selected, and makes an array with the necessary parameters to drive the rest of the page.

The problem comes with the fact that the created array never displays back into the main webpage. I would assume I need to push my newly created array into the HTML document.. but I've only done that with jquery before. And I **cannot** use jquery for this due to the restrictions we have on our pcs.

I'm looking for any help here.. I'm a bit of a novice of a coder and I'm trying my hardest not to edit/rewrite the code here.

Thanks.

Addendum 
The `makeDyLevelMenuItem` basically makes the array of menu items to list. It looks like this..

```
function makeDyLevelMenuItem(levelDyValue,levelDyLabel,levelDyDefault,levelDyClass) {
numDyLevelMenuItems++;
levelDyMenuItems[numDyLevelMenuItems] = new levelDyMenuItem(levelDyValue,levelDyLabel,levelDyDefault,levelDyClass);
}
```

Comment: What does `makeDyLevelMenuItem` do?

Comment: Use `document.createElement` to create the new `<option>` elements, and `appendChild` to add them to the select.

Comment: Don't try to put the code into a comment, add it to the question.